# Match and bind the fields of record type in one match pattern?

Tags: f#

Is it possible to match and bind the fields of record type in the match pattern statement?

```
type R = { A:int; B:string }
type R' = R option

let record: R' = .....
match record with
| Some(r) ->
     let a, b = r.A, r.B // Can this row be merged to the match pattern like the tuple example below?
     ....
| None -> ....
```

Expected something like the following for tuple

```
match record with 
| Some(a, b) -> ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
match record with
| Some({A = a; B = b }) -> ...
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in match pattern could be assigned not all fields of the record which is useful for records with many fields, like `Some({B = b }) -> // use b here ...`